# How to import Windows Live Mail mails into ThunderBird?

Tags: windows, email, thunderbird, windows-live-mail

I have a Windows machine and always use Windows Live Mail, but after a time I descovery that Windows Live Mail do not support filters in IMAP account.
So then I discover that Thunderbird that support this function so I would like to import these emails into Thunderbird.

How I import my email from Windows Live Mail into Thunderbird 12.0.1 ?

Comment: I did but some tutorials are old or it didn't import correctly.

Comment: Thunderbird 12.0.1

Comment: Yes, that's the exactly one that I tried and it didn't import my mail correctly. And I'm still trying to import reading some tutorials.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the Windows live email client (not webmail) open Live mail client, select the email account and inbox, highlight all the emails in the selected account inbox, right click drag them to a empty folder on your desktop, when you release the right clcik you should get a context menu, select "copy here". this will copy all the emails to that folder in the .eml format, then you should be able to import them from that folder [using this extension for Thunderbird](https://nic-nac-project.org/~kaosmos/mboximport-en.html) (newer versions of Thunderbird may be able to import .eml format without the extension, not sure)

.

[image]

Note: When dragging to the desktop folder it may appear it is doing nothing, be patient it takes a while to convert them to .eml format, and depending on how many emails you drag how long it takes.

Do this for each email account and folder you have, label the folders you drag them to, this keeps them sorted for import purposes.

[Importing the address book can be a little trickier](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=39&t=2189957)

Comment: +1 FYI, this two-staged method can be used to migrate mail into pretty much any client.

Answer (score 1):

I've spent days trying to find Kaosmos import tools in Thunderbird- it just was not there even after downloading again and re-applying the addon. Then I discovered another menu and there it was. The other menu can be seen by right clicking just below the top left tab area and checking "mail toolbar" and "menu bar". Click on tools and at the bottom is ImportExport tools.
Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MsgExtract](http://www.maildev.com/msgextract/) to transfer  your Windows Live Mail messages into Thunderbird. You just need to select the source folders in WLM and the target folder in Thunderbird.

(Disclaimer, I am the author of MsgExtract)